# JSON returns empty when data contains special characters

Tags: php, json

I am trying to show data from my database with JSON. But I have some issues with 'special characters'.

The data contains characters like: 'ë'. When I try to show the data, json returns an empty table.

Does someone know how I can fix this issue?

I am trying to show the data with the following code:

```
echo json_encode($json_data);
```

Comment: Yep, that is a thing.  Probably non UTF-8 stuff.

Comment: Could you paste an example of the output you have to work with? json encode really should be able to handle utf-8 just fine.

Comment: The input JSON data needs to be UTF-8 encoded and whoever generated it probably didn't do it correctly. Whoever is giving you that data needs to fix it. Chances are they're just barfing out ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Works for me, https://3v4l.org/bOb3u

Comment: add JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option: json_encode($json_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: An example of the output: `immateriële`. When I try to show this json returns empty. When I change `ë` to `e` it is working

Comment: I also tried to add `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` but it didnt change anything. JSON still returns empty

Comment: Is your text coming from a non-UTF8 source? Like a latin1 MySQL database or an iso-8859-xx text file? If so, try passing it through one of the `utf8_encode()`/`iconv()` type of functions before handing it to `json_encode()`.